# Oracle 12 C Equivalent for SQL Server CURSOR STATIC

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, cursor

I need to duplicate data in a table looping the current rows with a cursor.
Newly added rows need to be ignored in the loop.
In SQL Server I manage this using CURSOR STATIC which takes a snapshot of the query result.
I can't find the equivalent in Oracle 12 C.
Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is what Oracle does by default - the results of the query are determined at the outset and will not change while the cursor is open.  This is called **statement-level read consistency** and is described [here in the Concepts manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-E8CBA9C5-58E3-460F-A82A-850E0152E95C).